# Google Form script & HTML won't execute the called script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a form in Google scripts using an html page, which then calls a javascript function, [as documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication). When I run the app, the form loads just fine, but it will not execute the script. How can I make this work?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<html>
  <!--Create Sign Out Form-->
  <form id="signOut">

    <div>
      Destination: 
      <select name="destination">
        <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="meeting">Client Meeting</option>
        <option value="vacation">Vacation</option>
        <option value="sick">Out Sick</option>
        <option value="personal">Personal</option>
        <option value="home">Working from Home</option>
        <option value="scedule">Reduced Schedule</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      Supervisor: 
      <select name="supervisor" onselect="google.script.run.withUserObject(this.parentNode).populate(destination)"></select>
    </div>

    <div>
      Start Date: 
      <input type="date" name="startDate" onselect="google.script.run.withUserObject(this.parentNode).SignOutLibrary.dateSelect()"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      End Date: 
      <input type="date" name="endDate" onselect="google.script.run.withUserObject(this.parentNode).SignOutLibrary.dateSelect()"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      Details: 
      <textarea type="text" name="details" style="width: 150px; height: 75px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
             .sendRequest(this.parentNode)"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</html>
```

And the scripts it should be calling:

```
function doGet() {
  // Uses html form
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('request_form');
}
```

SignOutLibrary:

```
function dateSelect() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("change");
  var date = app.createDatePicker().setPixelSize(150, 150).addValueChangeHandler(handler).setId("date");
  app.add(date);
  return app;
}

function change(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(eventInfo.parameter.date);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: not that I've come across yet. (Assuming you are talking about the logger since there is no console :/)

Comment: I see in the documentation that there is an _onclick_, does anyone know if _onselect_ is supported?

Comment: Another update: the _onclick_ script for my submit button doesn't reven work? I even tried stting up a completely new library and form from scratch to b sure it wasn't some option I selected and they still aren't running.

Comment: AFAIK [tag:google-form] is for the Google Forms app not for forms created using the HTML Service for Google Apps Script. This tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try changing all the this.parentNode in your code with this.form

I quickly looked into the docs and MAYBE it'll work, sorry but I can't test my answer right now

Answer (score 0):

You don't show `populate()` - hopefully you do have such a function. If you do, then your next task would be to find a way to get a value for `destination` which you're passing as a parameter. In its present form, it's undefined. See [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript).

You can't call library functions directly using the script runner, see the bit on [Private Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions). You would need to add intermediary functions to your "local" gs to interface with the library functions such as `SignOutLibrary.dateSelect()`.

That library uses the UiApp, while the rest of your code uses the Html Service. Pick one or the other, because you can't mix them like this.